# Proper way of implementing MVP passive in C# .net

Tags: c#, mvp

In "MVP Passive" where

- a view doesn't know about it's presenter
- the view just raises events observed by the presenter,
- the presenter knows the view and its controls

how should view and presenter properly function/communicate with each other? I.e through methods, disposing of view/presenter, interpresenter, other view communication?

To be more specific,

- should a view contain some UI logic, or should all logic be in the presenter?
- if a view event is raised, should the presenter call a view's method which does several UI actions, or should the presenter do the magic and tell view about each individual control to change?

Comment: Your description of MVP seems backwards.  The benefit of MVP is in the other direction where the Presenter has no direct dependency on the View (Presenter containing UI logic and the view only contains layout/appearance with bare-minimum "glue" to communicate with the presenter).  This allows the UI logic to be built, designed and tested in isolation without needing any GUI components.

Comment: @BenCottrell: hmm i got my knowledge of mvp from robert marquez's vid series, What about minimize, maximize? Where do they go? Does the view have functions that the presenter calls upon receiving an event from the view? So the presenter doesn't have access to the view's controls? I'm new at this, so thanks for helping hehe :))

Comment: Minimise/Maximise are native features of a Window, controlled by properties on a Form - you don't need to implement any UI logic for those.   The presenter certainly shouldn't access any controls, and shouldn't have any direct reference to the View; instead the View would implement an interface exposing one or more methods and/or events (Allowing the view to be mocked for unit testing).  The project Robert Harvey linked to above is a good example

Comment: Here is a well-known and reasonably good implementation of MVP that you can study: https://github.com/DavidRogersDev/WinformsMVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the things already mentioned in the comments by @BenCotrell, in MVP, there is no hard-and-fast rule how much logic should be placed in the View, and how much in the Presenter. [Citing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter):

> The degree of logic permitted in the view varies among different implementations. At one extreme, the view is entirely passive, forwarding all interaction operations to the presenter. In this formulation, when a user triggers an event method of the view, it does nothing but invoke a method of the presenter that has no parameters and no return value. The presenter then retrieves data from the view through methods defined by the view interface. Finally, the presenter operates on the model and updates the view with the results of the operation.

vs.

> Other versions of model-view-presenter allow some latitude with respect to which class handles a particular interaction, event, or command. This is often more suitable for web-based architectures, where the view, which executes on a client's browser, may be the best place to handle a particular interaction or command.

Putting as much logic as possible in the Presenter will, in theory, allow more automated testing and less duplicated code between different View implementations. However, this also comes with certain disadvantages:

- It can make the interface between the Presenter and View very broad, requiring a lot of boilerplate interface implementation code.
- The Presenter may become responsible for a lot of things the UI framework itself could handle, or for things the View could handle by simpler means.
- The Presenter may become tightly designed to a very specific "physical" structure of the View, making it aware of several controls, their very specific types and event behaviour, their properties and failure handling.

As a strategy to resolve this, I would usually try to start with a lean Presenter, putting only the logic there for which it appears to be crystal-clear it is not really UI-framework specific. Then I would check if this is enough to write all the automated tests for the Presenter I would like to have - and if not, refactor.

Another litmus test is to provide two different View implementations (with different UI technologies, like a desktop technology and a web technology) for the same View. That could require some effort, of course, but it will definitely give the feedback if one placed the right things in the Presenter.

Answer (score 0):

Marquez videos are about a non-passive view. He doesn't like a passive view. Also, he implements some pretty advanced stuff such as event-managing. He even uses  a IoC container and advanced error-checking mechanisms and logging. All of his stuff can wait for now.

I advice to search for the title "**CRUD with MVP pattern, C#, WinForms and SQL Server**" and take your time. He implements the passive view. It's a good start. I did the same.

Once you start building you'll encounter practical design challenges and learn to solve them one-by-one, perhaps with a little bit of help

You already know that the View should be simple, so now something about the Presenter.

The presenter should do Presenter things, not CRUD operations. Nor should the Model do that. So what do you need? A repository! So you have **Model->Repository <-> Presenter <- View** . The title I gave you does that and also adopts an anemic model, so that part is also simple.

Make sure your C# fundamentals are OK, so you don't have to fight the language. And off you go - meaning get busy :).

**The trick is to implement basic MVP and then learn unit testing**. Now, when you unit-test your own MVP app, you'll find out soon enough what is needed to make your components testable, stand on their own and collaborate well. As long as you lack experience (skill is not enough), you'll always have questions like this.